# Implementing a trait only if another type implements that trait

Tags: rust

Context: I'm generating code (from a macro) that spits out new types. Of course, I don't have access to type information in my macro.

I want my type `NewStruct` (which I've generated) to implement a trait (say `Condition`) if and only if `Struct` (which passed as argument to the macro) implements that same type. Any idea how to do that?

Example:

```rust
trait Condition {
   fn is_valid(&self) -> bool;
}

// This struct implements `Condition`.
struct StructA{}
impl Condition for StructA {
    fn is_valid(&self) -> bool {
        true
    }
}

// This struct does not implements `Condition`.
struct StructB{}

// My macro.
// create_new_type!{type NewStructA from StructA};
// create_new_type!{type NewStructB from StructB};

// => generated code

struct NewStructA {
   value: StructA
}
impl Condition for NewStructA where StructA: Condition {
   fn is_valid(&self) -> bool {
      return Condition::condition(&self.value)
   }
}

struct NewStructB {
   value: StructB
}
impl Condition for NewStructB where StructB: Condition { // <- This fails with "the trait bound `Condition` is not implemented for `StructB`.
   fn is_valid(&self) -> bool {
      return Condition::condition(&self.value)
   }
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=59545f846a75e4c6b308ee318098794c)

**edit** Looks https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/2056-allow-trivial-where-clause-constraints.md and like https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/48214 .

Comment: What is `U`? Is it a generic type? What constrains it?

Comment: Usually `#[derive(Clone)]` takes care of that for you, although it can be overly strict (e.g. it doesn't implement `Clone` if your type contains a `PhantomData<U>` and `U` doesn't implement `Clone`.

Comment: @AleksanderKrauze `U` is a concrete type, passed as argument to my macro invocation.

Comment: @Thomas Fair enough, this works for `Clone` but not, for instance, for `Copy`. Do you know of anything more generic?

Comment: It happens to work for `Copy` too, but of course not for your own traits.

Comment: @Thomas I've just tested for `Copy` and it didn't work for me.

Comment: In any case, this question is impossible to answer conclusively without a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: @Thomas added an example.

Answer (score 1):

###### Note: `T` and `U` usually mean generic types, so I renamed them (`U -> Foo`, `T -> Bar`.

I *guess* (and only guess, since you didn't say what is your real use case) that type `Foo` is generated by your macro, and it *can* implement `Clone` (depending on user configuration) and you want to propagate this to type `Bar` which contains `Foo`. The only thing I can think about is to make `Bar` generic, and use a default value of generic type.

```rust
// Foo: Clone is conditional at compile time
// #[derive(Clone)]
struct Foo;

struct Bar<T = Foo> {
    foo: T
}

// This implies T = Foo. All Bar's methods will exist only for T = Foo.
// This is zero cost abstraction. Compiler will remove generic type completely.
impl Bar {
    fn baz(&self) {}
}

// This is the _only_ way to conditionally implement trait for a type
impl<T: Clone> Clone for Bar<T> {
    fn clone(&self) -> Self {
        Self { foo: self.foo.clone() }
    }
}

fn test1() {
    // If this is in another module you won't be even able to create Bar
    // with T oter than Foo, when foo is private field.
    let x: Bar<()> = Bar { foo: () };
    // This WON'T work, since all Bar methods are for T = Foo
    // x.baz();
}

fn test2() {
    let x: Bar = Bar { foo: Foo };
    // This will work only when Foo: Clone
    // x.clone();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I've rephrased my entire question to clarify.

Comment: @Yoric after seeing your example I believe that this solution will work for you.

Comment: It very much does - in fact, my prototype uses this trick. Sadly, when misused, this leads to confusing error messages down the line, so I'm exploring alternative designs.